# Is there CAS Authenticator version for WSO2IS 5.8 and later?

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I need to use CAS Authenticator for WSO2IS 5.8. I can't find in download site any version that compatible with 5.8 version.

Answer (score 0):

The 2.0.2 version of CAS authenticator and the versions released after 2.0.2 (2.0.3 and 2.0.4) supports for WSO2 IS 5.8.0 and 5.9.0 as well.

Please refer to this [doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ISCONNECTORS/Configuring+CAS+Inbound+Authenticator) for further information on CAS authenticator and download the authenticator from the [connector store](https://store.wso2.com/store/assets/isconnector/details/593aac68-3139-425c-b9ca-f66a65a0917a).